# Git command to list artefacts that have changed between commitA and commitB including those that have finally be reset to like in commitA

Tags: git, patch

This is needed to generate cumulative patches based on a given ReleaseCommitA.

The two commands `git log` and `git diff` can provide a list of artefacts that have evolved between two commits, but they miss an artefact that has changed multiple times in such a way it is back to as it was in ReleaseCommitA.
A customer that has alreay applied a patch since ReleaseCommitA must obtain this kind of artefact in a patch produced by this list.

A command that lists some artefacts multiple times would be fine.

Edit: 
I may have missed this point : we want to regularly produce a new cumulative patch for all our customers, but they are not all up to the same patch level (and not connected to our git commits in any way).
It is actually the production of a cumulative standard Service Pack for a given release : the patch must include all the commits since a given milestone commit. Our building process needs a list of all the concerned artefacts to prepare the patch.
As said in the first entry, we know how to produce that list with `git diff` or `git log`, except that some artefacts can be missing if they have been reset to the state as they were in **ReleaseCommitA**.
In short, we are somehow looking for an option in `git diff` or `git log` to report all the artefacts that have been concerned by a commit path whatever the action (Added Copied Deleted Modified Renamed etc... ), and we are also wondering if a new action is needed to handle the case of "file has changed some times but finally been reset to as it was in *commitA*".

Comment: If the user already applied a patch on ReleaseCommitA is not on that commit any more. Generate for them a diff between their current status and commit B.

Comment: Do you want a patch series that includes every commit, or just a few key steps - i.e. where is that customer patch in all of this? What about simply applying customer patch to a new branch starting at ReleaseA, then diff that result with ReleaseB, maybe...

Comment: Edit of first post.